# "Add view" context menu option missing, why/how do I get it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am new to ASP.NET Mvc, recently I started worked on a MVC application. I am unable to find the Add View option when you right click on Controller Action method.

I tried to add it by using Tools>Customize>Commands>Project.../folder/Menus. I am unable to find it. I tried right click on Views>Add>Add View. Then nothing turned up.

Please tell me how to add it? Here how it looks like when I right click on action method.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When right-clicking on a controller action name, I get the `Add View` option. However, you can also simply right-click on the `Views` folder and add a new View.

[image]

If it doesn't show, you probably didn't setup the controller correctly. Check the following

- Is the name of the controller something like "XXXXscontroller", e.g. "ArticlesController"
- Is there a view folder, e.g. "View/Articles"? Make sure the name is identical to the name of the controller without the "controller", i.e. ArticlesController --> Articles
- Rebuild the project

Comment: The OP is saying he doesn't have this menu item.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add in view folder. **Right click on view folder** then click on add and select view. Please give the name of view same as action name. So you no need to explicitly use the name of view in action method.

In between make sure your application not in running/debug mode. So stop before trying to add view.

Comment: Even when i Right Click on View Folder and try to add View, nothing is showing up.

Comment: Updated the answer please check if helpful.